# Граффити на сайте

Tags: php

Нужно, чтобы люди могли свои наброски рисовать и отправлять мне, но для этого нужен хороший визуальный редактор, встроенный прямо на сайт. Я сначала подумал вывести фреймом этот [сайт](http://pixlr.com/editor/?loc=ru), но в таком случаи придётся сначала сохранять, потом заливать, получается почти тоже самое, что и визуальный редактор на компе... Но я увидел возможность сохранять на imm.io, можно ли как-то эту ссылку достать в переменную? Или если это невозможно, то может есть какие-нибудь скрипты для такого графити?

Comment: Как «граффити» ВКонтакте? Надо искать видимо фриварную флэшку — должно быть много таких. Может поможет [обзор онлайн рисовалок](http://www.smashingapps.com/2010/07/22/top-15-online-tools-for-drawing-and-sketching.html).
p.s. pixlr крут - спасибо за ссылку!

Comment: Ссылка с imm.io возвращается в ответе от [API](http://imm.io/api/)

Comment: Только возвращается она на pixlr, я вот интересуюсь, возможно как-то перехватить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй [PixLR API](http://pixlr.com/developer/api).
Примерное решение(не проверял) - скачиваешь js-библиотеку, задаёшь настройки и на выходе получаешь ссылку на картинку.

Comment: О, спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: Это не совсем то, здесь редактор изображений, и то фиговый, в примере видно: http://developer.pixlr.com/ Мне бы хотелось именно такой, который у них